# Wordpress Concatenation

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

For the life of me, I can't seem to find an answer for this via Gsearch.

Writing a custom listing page for Wordpress, and the loop seems to strip everything that I concatenate except variables-- everything from p tags to commas and spaces are removed. Here's an example:

```
<?php the_field( "city_town" ) . ", " . the_field( "state" ) . " " . the_field( "zipcode" ); ?>
```

This results in:

```
CityST12345
```

Instead of

```
City, ST 12345
```

Is there something I can add to functions.php, or a file in wp-admin that I can manipulate, to force WP to acknowledge those concatenations?

Thanks in advance for any insight you might have!

Comment: Not sure what `the_field()` is referring to (it's not part of the core is it?) but try whether there is a `get_the_field()`, the `the_xxx` functions tend to echo the result, not return it

Comment: the_field is part of a plugin, Advanced Custom Fields-- sorry, I should have specified that.

Comment: I'd try whether there's a `get_the_field()`.

Comment: Aha, it's `get_field()`: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/

Comment: You were spot on, though...there is a function (get_field) that works with "echo" to keep tags and concatenation. Thanks so much! Problem solved. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it like this :

```
echo get_field('city_town').' : '. get_field('state');
```

or with sub field :

```
echo get_sub_field('city_town').' : '.get_sub_field('state');
```